# Como receber meu array na pagina JSP

Tags: array, jsp

```
public void Pesquisar(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try {
    Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/CadastroProdutos", "root", "maquinarafa");
    Statement comando = conexao.createStatement();
    String comandoSQL = "select id_produto, nome, descricao, fornecedor,quantidade,tipo, link  from cadastro_produtos"; 
    ResultSet rsClientes= comando.executeQuery(comandoSQL);
    while(rsClientes.next()){
        System.out.println(rsClientes.getString("id_produto")+";"
                                +rsClientes.getString("nome")+";"
                                +rsClientes.getString("descricao")+";"
                                +rsClientes.getString("fornecedor")+";"
                                +rsClientes.getString("quantidade")+";"
                                +rsClientes.getString("tipo")+";"
                                +rsClientes.getString("link"));
        String idd = rsClientes.getString("id_produto");
        String name = rsClientes.getString("nome");
         String desc =rsClientes.getString("descricao");
         String forn = rsClientes.getString ("fornecedor");
         String qtde = rsClientes.getString ("quantidade");
         String tip=rsClientes.getString ("tipo");
         String caminhoimag=rsClientes.getString("link");
         //adicionando para o objeto 
         Produto p2 = new Produto();
         p2.setId(idd);
         p2.setNome(name);
         p2.setDescricao(desc);
         p2.setFornecedor(forn);
         p2.setQuantidade(qtde);
         p2.setTipo(tip);
         p2.setLink(caminhoimag);
         p2.arrayproduto.add(p2);
        }
```

/////eu tenho um metodo que pesquisa e retorna meud dados do mysql para o arrayproduto , porem quero acessar este array em uma pagina JSP >>>>>

**JSP PAGE**

```
<%@page import="Classes.Produto"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Relatório de Produtos </title>
<h1 align = "center"> Relatório de Produtos </h1>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<%
Produto p = new Produto();
ArrayList<Produto> array =  ???? nao sei como receber este array na jsp
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Rafael,
Para ter acesso a esta collection no JSP vai depender de como você está fazendo a chamada pro JSP.

Caso esteja usando o método `request.getRequestDispachter().forward(req,resp)` então você consegue ter acesso a lista adicionando-a em um *request attribute* através do método `req.setAttribute("key", "value")`.

Caso esteja usando um `resp.sendRedirect()` dai fica um pouco mais chatinho. As opções não são tão viáveis assim como o método acima. O motivo disso é que com o método `resp.sendRedirect()` passa a responsabilidade da requisição para o cliente, e a Servlet deixa de renderizar essa page.
Uma das alternativas é usar uma sessão através do método `req.getSession().setAttribute("key", "value")` (Só não se esqueça que a sessão permanece ativa durante várias requisições. Então você teria que limpar quando necessário pra evitar confusão.

Suponho que você esteja usando o primeiro método (mais ideal).
No seu exemplo, ficaria algo assim..

`request.setAttribute("lista_produtos", p2.arrayproduto);`.

E no seu JSP, você teria acesso assim:

`<% List array = (List) request.getAttribute("lista_produtos"); %>`

Espero que tenha ajudado.
Abraços.